# Regex Multiple rows

Tags: regex, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google sheets that contains a block of text like this one, all in one  cell"

Wed Aug 26 10:45:06 CDT 2020 INFO: id: "gee"

Wed Aug 26 10:45:06 CDT 2020 INFO: id: "X"

Wed Aug 26 10:45:06 CDT 2020 INFO: id: "er"

I just want to get the id on google sheet,assuming this block is cell A1 normally I would write something like this

=REGEXTRACT(A1,".+") that would return id: "gee"

how can I make regex output all of them by going to the new line and not stopping at the logical one?like

id: "gee"

id: "X"

id: "er"

Comment: `=REGEXTRACT(A1,"\bid:\s*""[^""]+""")`?

Comment: I just get " id: "gee" " with this one it does not go to the newline to get "id: X" and so on